# Why does operator "new" require a pointer to work?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator, dynamic-memory-allocation

I cannot wrap my head around why the memory in the stack allocated through `new` can be accessed only through pointers, while the memory in the heap (statically allocated) can be accessed normally.

Does it have something to do with the fact that pretty much all memory in the heap has some sort of order and the one in the stack is somewhat random? (If what I just said is true at all.)

Dynamic memory just seems so vague and mystical to me, so anyone who could help me understand it better will be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You seem to be confused about terms here. You really ought to post a *code* sample that you find unclear. That way people could explain it to you.

Comment: that is what the new operator does: allocates the memory of a new object for you and creates a pointer to it

Comment: What makes it seem "mystical"? It is a totally deterministic and rules-based process, even if its inner workings are not readily apparent.

Comment: You 're basically asking why c++ works the way it does. Well, that's how it works. Deal with it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you've mixed up the stack (the storage of variables with automatic lifetime) and the heap (the storage of variables with dynamic lifetime, usually allocated by `new`).

Comment: So there's no particular reason

int* ptr = new int; works

and

int ptr = new int; doesn't

that was my question

Comment: @DanailNedkov `new` returns a pointer, so you can't directly assign it to an `int`. You could, however, do `int &i = *new int;` -- but that'd be particularly non-idiomatic.

Comment: @Quentin You can even do `int i = *new int;` (where you rely on the process exiting before you use up the address space)

Comment: @Caleth yes, but then we're not handling dynamic memory anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does operator “new” require a pointer to work?

Becouse it allocates block of memory (size is specified by caller) on `heap` and returns `address` of the beginning of that allocated block.

> Why are we using it

- We're using it if we want that memory temporary, so we can easily `delete[]` it.
- You can easily change the size of the allocated memory (resize).

  ```
  char arr[20]; // You need more space? Not possible to change size

  // While

  char * arr = new char[20];

  delete[] arr;

  arr = new char[50];
  ```

> Disadvantage

- Allocating object with `new` is much more expensive.
- Its slower.
- Memory leak's
- Memory fragmentation
- Has to be free'd `delete[]`

**Summary**

`Stack` (`automatic storage`) is easier to use, faster & foolproof. But sometimes we have to use `heap` and we should be careful as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

See, in C++, memory is divided into four parts, that are

1. Program code
2. Global variables
3. Stack
4. Heap

Now, as name defines **Program code part stores your code** and**Global variable part stores global variables**.
These two parts are very clear.

Now, our concern is *Stack memory* and *Heap memory*.

**Stack memory is reserved for static implementation**.

**Heap memory is reserved for dynamic implementation**.

Variables in stack memory are allocated during compilation.
But **variables in heap memory are allocated during runtime**, as it allocated during runtime we can't process it as normal variables.

> Here we require pointers because we **need something that refers us to the memory accquired during dynamic allocation**. This job is done by pointers.

Comment: Kudos for your contribution.  Technically, C++ does not have stack 'storage' and heap 'storage', it has (I think) dynamic storage and automatic storage.  On the other hand, stack and heap are probably mentioned more often.